# Trouble with destructor in overloaded = STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, destructor

I need to overload `=` to be able to make deep copy of instances of my class.
It works quite well untill I try to set as input lot of some random data. Then I get this message:

> Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=004042F3
>   and then it prints out the stack..

I assume, that I need to delete values in the arrays before copying it, nevertheless I can't figure out, how it shall look like.
I tried this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i != position-1; i++) {
    for (int j=0;j!=db[i]->position-1;j++)
        delete &db[i]->change[j];
    delete db[i];
}
delete[] db;
db = new DbPerson*[other.size];
```

, but it gets even worse and the program ends with failure even earlier..

here are the declarations of used components:

```
int size;
int position;
DbPerson** db;

...

class DbChange {
public:
DbChange();
const char* date;
const char* street;
const char* city;
};

DbChange::DbChange() {
date = "";
street = "";
city = "";
}

class DbPerson {
public:
DbPerson(void);
const char* id;
const char* name;
const char* surname;
DbChange * change;
int position;
int size;
};

DbPerson::DbPerson() {
position = 0;
size = 1;
change = new DbChange[1];
}
```

All arrays can be resized, when there is not enough space left, and actuall count of items saved in them, is saved in `position` variable. Pls dont advice me to use `Vector` or `string`, because I'm not allowed to use them. I'm sure, that the function, that overloads `=` sucessfuly ends and this error message is printed out when it tries to finish the assigment.

If somebody coudl show me, how shall the destructor look like, I'd be really glad because, I already tried to solve this thing for several hours and without any success :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to **pre-delete** DbChange within each object of DbPerson. You can just call the destructor for DbChange within DbPerson.

Take a look:

```
class DbChange
{
public:
     const char* id;
     const char* Name;

     DbChange(): id(""), Name("")
     {}

     ~DbChange()
     {
         delete [] id;
         delete [] Name;
     }
 };

class DbPerson
{
 public:
    const char* id;
    const char* name;
    const char* surname;
    DbChange * change;
    int position;
    int size;

    DbPerson(): id(""), name(""), surname(""), position(0), size(1)
    {
        change = new DbChange[1];
    }

    void SHOW(void) const
    {
        cout << "Name:      " << name << endl
             << "Surname:   " << surname << endl
             << "position:  " << position << endl;
    }

    ~DbPerson()
    {
        delete [] change; // Calling Destructor for DbChange
        delete [] id;
        delete [] name;
        delete [] surname;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const int global_size_of_DbPerson = 10;
    DbPerson** db;
    db = new DbPerson* [global_size_of_DbPerson];

    for(int i = 0; i < global_size_of_DbPerson; i++)
    {
        db[i] = new DbPerson [global_size_of_DbPerson];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < global_size_of_DbPerson; i++)
    {
        delete [] db[i];
    }

    cout << "It Worked\n";
    delete [] db;

    return 0;
}
```